# How do i go to another php page with Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook

This is my facebook login button in my index.php

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div>
```

what do i do i need to add so that when i click the login button it goes to another php file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use `.click()` to do something when it gets clicked and then do a redirect with `window.location.href`.

```
$(".fb-login-button").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "link_to_new_page";
});
```

Throw this in `<script>`-tag in `<head></head>` or before `</body>`.

edit: While saying that, wouldn't just a link element `<a href='link'><div here></a>` work?